# Is there any Javascript TCP Soket Library for PHP like SignalR with .NET?

Tags: php, signalr

I found SignalR library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications.

Is there any similar library for php that also do the same job like signalR??

Comment: The terminology you might be looking for is Comet or WebSockets, or possibly SSE (Server Sent Events). SSE and WebSockets don't have widespread support though. Also I'm not that experienced at php though

Answer (score 6):

Yes please find information at:

(1) http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

(2) As well as can Creating Real Time Applications with PHP and WebSockets

PHPWebSockets is a WebSockets server written in PHP (https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets).

The WebSocket server itself is a class that can be extended to write the rest of the application. The WebSockets.php is the base class and we need to extend that class to write our own simple WebSocket server application. The WebSockets.php base class does the socket management and WebSocket handshake.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Ratchet 
follow below link

[php library](http://socketo.me/docs/)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Here is a link on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

Yes their is some other also.

If you don't want to code so much and your requirement is just push notification then do some research on [ONESIGNAL](https://onesignal.com/).

Follow these links:

[OneSignal Documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs)

[OneSignal API Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference)

- Make Free Account.
- Register your Application with ONESIGNAL
- Consume ONESIGNAL api in your project with their few lines generic code.

Comment: Websocket != Push notifications