# Audio Player That Plays Audio For Everyone on Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I would like to make a webpage where anyone on it will be able to play the uploaded sounds that are on the webserver. For example, the webpage would have a sound and a button once the button is clicked the sound will play not only on your side but on the side of anyone else on the webpage. I'm using WordPress but I have experience with HTML, JavaScript, and PHP so if needed to dive into some coding I won't mind. If you could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You would need some kind of websocket or p2p connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of what you explaining you will need to look into WebSockets. this is what you need for 2 way communication between your client and server.

I don't have experience doing this in PHP but from my searching, you might want to look into Ratchet (check out that is mentioned this stack post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473356/is-there-any-javascript-tcp-soket-library-for-php-like-signalr-with-net)).

This example app might help http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: Sorry for the late response it's been a crazy few weeks! Thank you for responding I appreciate that I will look into WebSockets!

Comment: no problem and glad to hear it. if you don't mind can you upvote it as well?